# Error on merging ppt files using visual basic scripting

Tags: vbscript

I am a newbie to visual basic scripting..
I was trying to combine multiple ppt files into a single ppt using the following .vbs code.
it was supposed to create a new ppt called merged.ppt from all the ppts stored in a subfolder called PPTmerge.

But on executing I get error on line:

```
 Set out = Application.Presentations.Open(f)
```

Can someone help me please...!

```
Const PPTMERGE_FILE = "Merged.ppt"
Const PPTMERGE_FOLDER = ".\PPTmerge"

Dim Application
Set Application=CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Application.Visible = True 'must do this for merge to work

Dim first  'to open power point only once
first = True

Dim fs
Set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim folder
Set folder = fs.GetFolder(PPTMERGE_FOLDER)

Dim out
Dim f

Dim ff
For Each ff in folder.Files
f = PPTMERGE_FOLDER + "\" + ff.Name
If first Then
  Dim p
  Set out = Application.Presentations.Open(f)
  out.SaveAs PPTMERGE_FOLDER + "\..\" + PPTMERGE_FILE
  first = False
Else
  out.Slides.InsertFromFile f, out.Slides.Count
End If
Next
If Not first Then
out.Save
out.SlideShowSettings.Run
'out.Close
End If
Set folder = Nothing

Set out = Nothing

Set folder = Nothing

'Application.Quit
Set Application = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified the full path name.

```
Try const pptmerge_folder = "full path name here"
```

The code on line 2.